# GoatCounter invalid URL for tracking domain

Tags: html, css

I got a basic static website that I want to implement Goatcounter on. I put the following tracking script on the index page.

```
<script data-goatcounter="https://MY_SITE.goatcounter.com/count" async src="//gc.zgo.at/count.js"></script>
```

But when trying to load the file locally, (not on a sever, just as a file) Firefox and  Chromium both fail to load it, with the error:

```
GET file://gc.zgo.at/count.js net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

Maybe the issue lies in running it locally?

Edit: I've disabled all ad/tracking blockers in my browser for testing.

Comment: [https://]gc.zgo.at/count.js

Comment: Maybe the double slash causes the error.

Comment: with the added https:// it now prints out `goatcounter: not counting because of: localfile` I guess that means it works now, but not when loaded as a locale file. But now the question is, why does the documentation state use it.

Comment: _"But now the question is, why does the documentation state use it."_ - Why the documentation says to use `//gc.zgo.at/count.js`, you mean? Because that will automatically make it pick the right protocol, matching the one you used to request your site - if you accessed it via HTTPS, then this will request `https://gc.zgo.at/count.js`, if you accessed your site via HTTP only, then it will request `http://gc.zgo.at/count.js`

Comment: Yes that was my question. That makes sense, didn't know that. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol in the script was missing.
The **wrong** way:

```
<script data-goatcounter="https://MY_SITE.goatcounter.com/count" async src="//gc.zgo.at/count.js"></script>
```

The **right** way:

```
<script data-goatcounter="https://MY_SITE.goatcounter.com/count" async src="https://gc.zgo.at/count.js"></script>
```